# how to insert every two li s in ul using javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am developing an html5 application using backbone.js. The format of html includes list elements. The labels of `li` elements come from web service.I am populating `li` elements dynamically .

I am taking all the labels in a collection and sending to Template. 
Now I want to insert every 2 `li` elements in `ul` elements dynamically.How can I achieve that?

My html is looking like

```
<div class="auto_data">  
<li>  
<label style="color:white">Name<sup>*</sup></label><input type="text">  
</li>  
<li>
<label style="color:white">Age<sup>*</sup></label><input type="text">  
</li>  
<li><label style="color:white">Gender<sup>*</sup></label><input type="text">  
</li>  
<li>  
<label style="color:white">salutation<sup>*</sup></label><input type="text">  
</li>  
</div>
```

Now i want to insert ul element for every two li elements

```
<ul>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
</ul>
```

Now Iam writing in my view
like

```
 _.each(this.questionReferenceCollection.models,function(model){
                                      uiControl=model.get('UIControlType');
                                      if(i==0){
                                      $('.auto_data',self.el).append('<ul>');
                                      }
                                      i++;

                                       $('.auto_data',self.el).append(new questions({
                                                                       model:model,
                                                                       controlType:uiControl
                                                                       }).render().el);/* this will render li template */
                                       if(i==2){
                                       $('.auto_data',self.el).append('</ul>');
                                       i=0;
                                       }

                                       });
```

But because of asynchronous call,

it results in

```
   <ul></ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <ul></ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
```

I want

```
<ul>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Can you provide some code for us to look at?  The HTML before, the data that you want to add and the HTML that you are looking to have at the end would be very helpful.  Any JS that you have tried already would be helpful too.

Comment: @talemyn I provided code above..

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the collection in your template for example. In that loop you can use the modulo operator (%) to determine whether or not the current index is dividable by 2. If so, you add a closing ul and an opening ul at that point.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Updated with a slightly more simple approach.

This is a little trickier than it first looks, but by using some creative selectors, the code to do it isn't too bad in the end:

```
var $autoDataDiv = $(".auto_data");

while ($autoDataDiv.children("li").length > 0) {
    var $newUL = $("<ul />");

    $newUL.append($autoDataDiv.children("li:first"));
    if ($autoDataDiv.children("li:first")) {
        $newUL.append($autoDataDiv.children("li:first"));
    }

    $autoDataDiv.append($newUL);        
}
```

Basically, what it does is selects the `<li>` elements that are immediate children of the "auto_data" `<div>` and then moves them in pairs into newly created `<ul>` elements and then appends those elements to the original parent `<div>`.

The "trickiest" part of the code is the fact that you use `$autoDataDiv.children("li:first")` twice when moving the `<li>`'s to the new `<ul>`.  The reason why that works is that, when an `<li>` is moved into the new `<ul>`, it is no longer an immediate child of the "auto_data" `<div>` and, therefore, is no longer returned by the selector.  So, when the first `<li>` that gets moved over to the `<ul>`, it disappears from the selection group and the next `<li>` moves into it's place as the one returned by `$autoDataDiv.children("li:first")`.

Anyway, this should work for you . . . let me know if you have any questions.